# How to calculate average waiting time in preemptive priority scheduling

Tags: process, scheduling

Given the following table :

[image]

I want to calculate the average waiting time of preemptive priority scheduling .

In the table above , the bigger the number is (in the priority column) the higher the priority is .

Partial solution :

```
|p1|p3|p1|p2|p5|p4|
0  8  29 33 52 67 80
```

What do I do from here ?

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

did  you understand the partial solution (the actual schedule) you have posted?

`Waiting time of a process = finish time of that process - execution time - arrival time`

Once you have this for all process then just take the average. That would give you the avg waiting time of the scheduling algorithm for this instance

More details:

Here process `p1` did not wait for the first 8 seconds. Then at t=9 it was preempted. It was in wait mode from time t=9 to t=29 while process `p3` was executing. So `p1` had waited for 21 seconds while `p3` was executing. At t=29, `p1` started again and completed at t=33. In total, `p1` had waited for 21 seconds. As per the formula we get waiting time as 33-12-0=21. Basically for each process we look at the time between when it arrived and when it finished. Any time between this interval when it is not executing is a wait time

Comment: Yes I did , but process `p1` is running from `0-8` and from `29-33` . How do I deal with him ? thanks

Comment: here p1 did not wait for the first 8 seconds. then at t=9 it was preempted. then it was in wait mode from 9 to 29 while p3 was executing. So p1 had waited for 21 seconds of p3's execution. At 29 it started again and completed at 33. Now in total p1 had waited for 21 seconds. As per the formula you get, 33-12-0=21. Now do you get how this formula works. Basically for each process you look at the time between when it arrived and when it finished. Any time between this interval when it is not executing is a wait time.

Comment: Start is 0. End it 33.  Execution is 8+4=12.